# Shipment / tracking creation slow in admin

Tags: admin, invoice, shipment, create-invoice

We have a problem with creating shipments in magento.

It's taking over a minute to create a shipment and e-mail the customer.

The problem started two weeks ago, and I have checked the logs and opened the firebug console during shipment creation. They all show no errors, only that it indeed takes about a minute to create the shipment (around 67 seconds).

Invoices can be created without a problem. Invoices with a tracking number are also taking a long time ofcourse.

We also emptied most of the abandoned carts, because it was the biggest log in the database. The other known big logs are being cleaned every night.

One extension that uses the shipment creation has been turned off, but unfortunately that didn't work.

Any idea what we could try next? Is there a tracking number log in Mysql we should empty?

We are using magento 1.8.0 and only flatrate shipping options (nothing with an API).

Comment: You can [enable the profiler only for admin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11186700/2047249) and see what's taking so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran an exact copy of the store locally, and changed the mailserver. The time it took to create a shipment was now cut down to 7 seconds.

I've contacted the hosting company with this information, and they changed the mailserver (unfortunately I don't know what they've changed exactly).

Now the time to process the order/invoice/tracking is normal again.

So the problem was the mailserver.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, so that this question will not count as "unanswered" anymore.